# Panda's evaluating NULL to NULL as false when comparing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a python program to do adhoc comparisons of different source files in a OLD -> NEW style compare. Currently I am merging the DF's and using np.where to evaluate differences, the issue I am facing is when the data in both comparison columns is null it evaluates as a difference rather than no difference. The existence of a difference is calculated in a new column labeled "diff".

DF1

| CODE | EFF_DT |
| --- | --- |
| XYZ | 1/1/2022 |
| ABC | 1/1/2022 |
| 123 |  |

DF2

| CODE | EFF_DT |
| --- | --- |
| XYZ | 4/1/2022 |
| ABC | 1/1/2022 |
| 123 |  |

```
ColNames= ['CODE', 'EFF_DT']

df1 = pd.read_excel(sourcefile1.xlsx, header=1, names=ColNames)
df2 = pd.read_excel(sourcefile2.xlsx, header=1, names=ColNames)

dfResults = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='code', 
                     right_on='code', suffixes=('_old','_new')

#remove key from list
ColNames.remove('CODE')

#do compare and calculate diffs, done this way to evaluate N number cols

for z in names:
    dfResults[z,'diff'] = np.where(dfResults[z + '_old'] ==
                                   dfResults[z + '_new'],  '', 'Diff')

#filter out rows with no diff
dfResults  = dfResults[dfResults.isin(['Diff']).any(axis=1)]

print(dfResults)
```

Actual Result:

| CODE | EFF_DT_old | EFF_DT_new | (EFF_DT), 'diff' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 1/1/2022 | 4/1/2022 | Diff |
| 123 |  |  | Diff |

Expected Result:

| CODE | EFF_DT_old | EFF_DT_new | (EFF_DT), 'diff' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 1/1/2022 | 4/1/2022 | Diff |

How do I make the np.where condition evaluate null == null as TRUE instead of FALSE?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: And if you try to put something like an extra comparison ```(dfResults[z + '_old'] == dfResults[z + '_new'] or dfResults[z + '_old'] != null )``` no I know how the 'np' library works and I don't know how it sorts empty values, so try changing 'null ' to what it uses

Comment: Actually filling null with a value works, thank you. Was thinking that would work but didn't try it. I will just fill with Nan then remove Nan after the compare for my output.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make a string and not a boolean out of your `diff` column? Besides why do you loop over `names`?

I think what you're trying to achieve can be done without `where` and dropping rows with `None`/`NULL`/`NaN`:

```
dfResults = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='CODE', 
                     right_on='CODE', suffixes=('_old','_new'))

dfResults['diff'] = dfResults['EFF_DT_old'] !=  dfResults['EFF_DT_new']
print(dfResults[dfResults['diff']].dropna())
```

Output:

```
  CODE EFF_DT_old EFF_DT_new  diff
0  XYZ   1/1/2022   4/1/2022  True
```

Does this address your problem?

Comment: Loop over names because I need to be able to run this adhoc for spread sheets that may have like 40+ columns in them and do the compare on every column. This way I do not need to specify list of columns for the potentially hundreds of different source files that need the adhoc compare done. I can still loop with your compare logic though, it is cleaner and I will try that as well. Also, plugging diff is just trying to give Operations the output that matches what they had been manually doing, I see no issue with True vs Diff.

Comment: Also reason why col names is explicit in this example is just for simplicity. I am deriving names by reading the spreadsheets header col in the actual program.

Comment: Using a bool will be easier on memory and leads to cleaner code while filtering: `dfResults[dfResults['diff']]`

Answer (score 0):

By filling the Null column with a value I was able to produce the expected result.

```
ColNames= ['CODE', 'EFF_DT']

df1 = pd.read_excel(sourcefile1.xlsx, header=1, names=ColNames)
df2 = pd.read_excel(sourcefile2.xlsx, header=1, names=ColNames)

for i in ColNames:
    df1[i].fillna("Nan",inplace=True)
    df2[i].fillna("Nan",inplace=True)

dfResults = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='code', 
                     right_on='code', suffixes=('_old','_new')

#remove key from list
ColNames.remove('CODE')

#do compare and calculate diffs, done this way to evaluate N number cols

for z in names:
    dfResults[z,'diff'] = np.where(dfResults[z + '_old'] ==
                                   dfResults[z + '_new'],  '', 'Diff')

#filter out rows with no diff
dfResults  = dfResults[dfResults.isin(['Diff']).any(axis=1)]

print(dfResults)
```

| CODE | EFF_DT_old | EFF_DT_new | (EFF_DT), 'diff' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 1/1/2022 | 4/1/2022 | Diff |